# bad decrypt when trying to decrypt a AES-CBC encrypted file using openssl

Tags: python, openssl, cryptography, aes, cbc-mode

I'm trying to encrypt a file with python, like so:

```py
import os
from binascii import hexlify
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes

key = hexlify(os.urandom(16))
print(key.decode())
iv = hexlify(os.urandom(16))
print(iv[:16].decode())
cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv[:16]))
encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
msg = b"a secret message"
ct = encryptor.update(msg) + encryptor.finalize()
open("ciphertext.bin", "wb").write(ct)
```

and then I try to decrypt it using openSSL(I have to use openSSL as it was requested by my professor) to check for success, like so:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -d -K <key_the_program_prints> -iv <iv_the_program_prints> -in ciphertext.bin -out res.txt
```

but I get:

```
hex string is too short, padding with zero bytes to length
bad decrypt
139711335437696:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:583:
```

What am I doing wrong? I believe I have the correct size in all the components, so I don't understand the error

Does it have anything to do with python handling the key and iv in bytes and I using them in string format for openSSL?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Python code, key (16 bytes for AES-128) and IV (16 bytes for AES) must be passed binary. In the OpenSSL statement they must be specified hexadecimal encoded, i.e. in the Python code use:

```
key = os.urandom(16)
print(hexlify(key)) # for OpenSSL
iv = os.urandom(16)
print(hexlify(iv)) # for OpenSSL
```

This also means that `iv` can be used directly instead of `iv[:16]` during the `Cipher` instantiation.

The *Cryptography* library does not pad automatically. However, OpenSSL applies PKCS7 padding by default. This must therefore be disabled with the *-nopad* option in the OpenSSL statement, [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-enc.html).

Please note that without padding only plaintexts whose length is an integer multiple of the AES block size (16 bytes) can be encrypted. Otherwise a padding must be applied. The *Cryptography* library supports several padding variants, including PKCS7, [here](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/padding.html?highlight=padding#module-cryptography.hazmat.primitives.padding). With padding, of course, the *-nopad* option in the OpenSSL statement must be removed.

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved one of my applied cryptography assignments! Merry Christmas!